AJV custom keyword with subschema validation
I'm using AJV to validate a JSON based on some JSON Schema.
I'd like to define a custom keyword that applies validation from a subschema based on some condition of the data (basically a more flexible version of discriminator).
For example:
{
    "mykeyword": {
        "even": {
            "properties": {
                "p": {"type": "string"}
            }
        },
        "odd": {
            "properties": {
                "p": {"type": "number"}
            }
        }
    }
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "n": "number"
    }
}

I'd like to figure out how to implement the following logic:
if ( data.n % 2 == 0 )
    validate(schema.even, data)
else
    validate(schema.odd, data)

Meaning selecting the right schema to validate against based on some condition.
It seems to be possible using the code custom keyword definition but their documentation only provides trivial examples.
For some context on my actual use case: the schema has its definitions in oneOf, I only want to validate the correct one but the provided discriminator is not enough to figure out which schema to validate. Not doing this causes AJV to return errors for every possible schema in oneOf which I don't want.

can you share your oneOf schemas?  it's possible you have an invalid schema defined and we can help you do it without customization

The schemas can be rather complex, hence the need to have custom logic to match only one of them based on specific conditions

You can do that with JSON Schema.  If your willing to share, someone can help you, regardless of the complexity. If it can't be done, we will tell you that too.

I'd really rather not have to edit the schema. #/$defs/layers/all-layers in https://lottie.github.io/lottie-spec/lottie.schema.json is one of the places this would be used for

are you having trouble with the if, then or enum and oneOf combinations?   I see quite a few things that can be tidied up in your schema

what about the layers schema are you having trouble with?

Validation works fine but, as I mentioned in the post, if validation fails AJV does not give a clean error message

For what it's worth, I managed to write a keyword using validate rather than code. That looks something like this:
{
    keyword: "mykeyword",
    validate: function validate_mykeyword(schema, data, parent_schema, data_cxt)
    {
        var sub_schema = get_schema_id_based_on_condition(data, schema);
        if ( sub_schema === undefined )
        {
            validate_mykeyword.errors = [{
                message: "Custom error",
                instancePath: data_cxt.instancePath,
                parentSchema: parent_schema,
            }];
            return false;
        }

        var validate = this.getSchema(sub_schema);
        if ( !validate(data, data_cxt) )
        {
            validate_mykeyword.errors = validate.errors;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Some things worth noting: validate must be a named function so you can get this value properly (which will be set to the Ajv instance) and to set errors which need to be a property of the function itself.
